# Confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, php, html

I like to add confirmation dialog. like"confirm adding (the amount)?" if yes it will proceed to addcontribution.php and if no it will go back to itself and reset the field.

```
<form form="CONTRIFORM" name='contribution' method="POST" Action="addcontribution.php" onSubmit="return formvalidation2();">
  <center>
    Amount:
    <input type="text" name="contriamnt" id="contriamnt" size="15" placeholder=" Amount"></br></br>
    <button id="searchbutton" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">ADD</button></br>
  </center>
</form> 

<script>

function formvalidation2() {
    var amntDATA = document.contribution.contriamnt;  
    if(allnumber(amntDATA)) {  
        if(ChangeText()) {
            if(new_tab()) {
            }
        }
    } 
    return false;  
}

function allnumber(amntDATA) {   
    var x = /^[0-9]+$/;  
    if(amntDATA.value.match(x)) {  
        return true;
    } else {  
        alert('Invalid Amount.');  
        return false;  
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Confirm function in js will help you

Answer (score 1):

Example

```
if (confirm('Confirm Adding (the amount)?')){
  window.location = "http://www.google.com/"; // your Custom Link
}else{
  document.getElementById('contriamnt').value="";
}
```